# Sentence builder java

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, methods

I am attempting to make this code take each variable, pass it down to the builder method and have it create a full sentence based on what was input by the user. The builder method passes it back to the main method and prints out the complete sentence consisting of "subject + verb + adjective + object + adverb".

Do I need to store each user input into an ArrayList? If so, how do I prompt the user for each new sentence piece? I've tried using for loops, however it just asks me for the first line 5 times, assuming I make the Array[5].

```
package assignment.pkg4.pkg3.string.input;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment43StringInput {
    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print("Enter a subject: ");
        String subject = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter a verb: ");
        String verb = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter an adjective: ");
        String adjective = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter an object: ");
        String object = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter an adverb: ");
        String adverb = scanner.nextLine();


        System.out.print(builder(text));

    }

    public static String builder(String text) {
        String sentence = subject + verb + adjective + object + adverb;
        return sentence;
    }            
}
```

Comment: suppose you can add them to an `ArrayList` and retrieve them in the `builder` method.

Comment: There's no law against accessing elements of an array without a `for` loop, if you choose to use an array to collect your pieces.  For example, `words[0] = ...`, `words[3] = ...`, etc.

Comment: Thank you! I think I'm going to use the Map option listed below.  Seems to give me some added flexibility if I want to reuse the code in the future.  I appreciate the input.

Comment: What's the problem having separate variable storing each word?  The question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to use one unique structure instead of one variable for each input. If you know your size is always going to be 5 and will not change, then you can use `String[]`. Alternatively, you can use a `List`.

But if you want to know exactly what is what, you might want to give `Map` a go. I'll explain it with an example:

```
public class Assignment43StringInput {
  private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    System.out.print("Enter a subject: ");
    map.put("subject", scanner.nextLine());

    System.out.print("Enter a verb: ");
    map.put("verb", scanner.nextLine());

    System.out.print("Enter an adjective: ");
    map.put("adjective", scanner.nextLine());

    System.out.print("Enter an object: ");
    map.put("object", scanner.nextLine());

    System.out.print("Enter an adverb: ");
    map.put("adverb", scanner.nextLine());

    System.out.print(builder(map));
  }

  public static String builder(Map<String,String> map) {
    return map.get("subject") + " " + map.get("verb") + " " + map.get("adjective") + " " + map.get("object") + " " + map.get("adverb");
  }            
}
```

This way you can easily reorder your sentence if you need to, and even add more elements to it.

Comment: Map definitely seems to be the way to go! Extremely helpful. Thank you very much

Comment: @JohnReynolds my most used structure by far. Maps are extremely versatile. As a general rule, try to avoid using `String` as key, as performance is not so good. Try to use `Integer` if possible. But for a small `Map` like yours it really makes very little difference.

Comment: why use a Map? A simple class is more suitable here.

Comment: A simple class? I don't see any advantages for that over a `Map`. In fact, using a class here is an example of over-engineering.

Comment: @AdrianShum would you mind explaining why a class is a better solution in this case? I'm curious

Comment: 1. It won't go wrong by accidentally putting wrong keys in the map . 2. You can put meaningful behavior to that class, for example, to construct a sentence.  3. it use less memory 4. it performs better 5. I simply cannot think of any reason why Map is a better choice here (maybe it save you several lines of code?)

Comment: Actually, in real case for such school work, I will neither use a class nor a Map.  Simply make the `builder()` method taking 5 strings, each with proper argument name, is good enough.

Comment: @AdrianShum as much as I see that your solution is also correct, I feel it's an overkill. It makes the code much harder to read just to store a bunch of variable and provide a number of getters for them.
Also, if we are going down the simplest case, we don't even need the `builder` method. Just print the concatenation and done.
To sum up, I see the `Map` solution simple and concise (based on what the OP askas), and the class solution a lot more convoluted for this simple use case. But if you feel so strong about, why didn't you write your own solution?

Comment: Even a class with only public variables is way better than a Map here.  I am just so surprised people will consider a simple class as "over-engineering".

Comment: We have different opinions here. I think using a class for a simple solutions leads to overengineering. You think a map is unefficient. I definitely encourage you again to write your own answer to this question so that your solution can also be seen.

Comment: Well, I haven't provided any answer, because the question itself is poorly asked and I have no clue why a Map/class can come into picture :P Anyway, adding one now as you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need array or Map or whatever.  To properly achieve your requirement, you just need to make your `builder` (I'd rather call it `buildSentence`, as method is supposed to be a verb) accept corresponding arguments:

```
public static String buildSentence(String subject, 
                                    String verb, 
                                    String adj, 
                                    String obj, 
                                    String adverb) {
    return subject + " " + verb + " " 
           + adjective + " " + object + " " + adverb;
}
```

and you simply call it with your variables passed in correspondingly:

```
System.out.print(buildSentence(subject, verb, adjective, object, adverb));
```

---

Regarding use of Array/ ArrayList/ Map, given you have a very well-defined sets of values to use, you shouldn't use these data structure as they are too versatile and making your code hard to read and error-prone.  Declare a simple class to serve for struct-like purpose is a much better choice:

```
class Sentence {
    public String subject;
    public String verb;
    public String adjective;
    public String object;
    public String adverb;
}
```

In your main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Sentence sentence = new Sentence();

    System.out.print("Enter a subject: ");
    sentence.subject = scanner.nextLine();
    // do the same for other values

    System.out.print(buildString(sentence));
}

public static String buildString(Sentence sentence) {
    return sentence.subject + " " 
         + sentence.verb + " " 
         + sentence.adjective + " " 
         + sentence.object + " " 
         + sentence.adverb;
}
```

See how much clearer and readable the code become?

A even better change is to move `buildString()` above as a member method of `Sentence`.

Comment: I agree this is very readable and looks very neat! Thank you, I can actually use this in the following weeks for the java course I am in.